# Why does the Delta 4 Heavy look burned?

Tags: launch, rockets, delta-iv-heavy

When I was looking at pictures of the Delta 4 Heavy rocket, I noticed that closer to the engines, the rocket looks black instead of the orange color it has right after launch. It looks burned to me.

My question is, why is that or what causes that?
[image]

[image]

Comment: see also https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/for-a-3-booster-rocket-why-do-they-start-with-igniting-the-starboard-booster-f/1653#1653